# Why MySQL performs full table scan if subquery is used in update statement

Tags: mysql, update, subquery, mysql-5.7

I have a test table:

```
create table t1 (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `description` varchar(120) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
insert into t1 (`description`)
         values ('d1'),('d2'),('d3'),('d4'),('d5'),
                ('d6'),('d7'),('d8'),('d9'),('d10');
```

Now let's look the following EXPLAINations of the query plans:

A:

```
mysql> explain update t1 set description='new_description' where id in (5,6);
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra                        |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+------------------------------+
|  1 | UPDATE      | t1    | NULL       | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const |    2 |   100.00 | Using where; Using temporary |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

B:

```
mysql> explain update t1 set description='new_description'
           where id in (select id
              from (select id from t1 where id in (5,6)) tmp);
+----+--------------------+------------+------------+----------------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+------+----------+------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table      | partitions | type           | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                        |
+----+--------------------+------------+------------+----------------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+------+----------+------------------------------+
|  1 | UPDATE             | t1         | NULL       | index          | NULL          | PRIMARY     | 4       | NULL |   10 |   100.00 | Using where; Using temporary |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | <derived3> | NULL       | index_subquery | <auto_key0>   | <auto_key0> | 4       | func |    2 |   100.00 | Using index                  |
|  3 | DERIVED            | t1         | NULL       | range          | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY     | 4       | NULL |    2 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index     |
+----+--------------------+------------+------------+----------------+---------------+-------------+---------+------+------+----------+------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

These queries do the same thing, but query B uses subquery.

Could you please help me with understanding why in query "B" MySQL performs full table scan(10 rows)? As subquery returns only 2 rows.

UPDATE:
It seems that it is related not only to a subquery, but to "in" operator too:

```
mysql> explain update t1 set description='new_description'
              where id = (select id from
                 (select id from t1 where id =5) tmp);
+----+-------------+------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | partitions | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | UPDATE      | t1         | NULL       | range  | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const |    1 |   100.00 | Using where |
|  2 | SUBQUERY    | <derived3> | NULL       | system | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL  |    1 |   100.00 | NULL        |
|  3 | DERIVED     | t1         | NULL       | const  | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const |    1 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+-------------+------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

AFAIS, with "=" operator MySQL process only 1 row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IN ( SELECT ... )` has always been poorly optimized in MySQL.  There were improvements in 5.6, but it does not seem to cover your case.  File a bug with http://bugs.mysql.com if you like.

It is often better to change to a `JOIN` since it optimizes better.  (I assume your *real* query is more involved, and you simplified it for this Forum.)

You can verify whether it does a table scan:

```
FLUSH STATUS;
perform the operation
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
```

Meanwhile, the "rows" in `EXPLAIN` is pessimistic in some situations.  I would trust the Handler counts when in doubt.  With 15 rows instead of 10, I got (excluding 0 values):

```
| Handler_commit             | 1     |
| Handler_external_lock      | 4     |
| Handler_read_first         | 1     |
| Handler_read_key           | 18    |
| Handler_read_rnd_next      | 16    |
| Handler_update             | 2     |
| Handler_write              | 2     |
```

That smells like a tmp table with 2 rows, plus a full scan (maybe twice?) of 15 rows, plus some other miscellany.

Comment: I have found the following limitation in the documentation (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subquery-optimization.html): 
    A limitation on UPDATE and DELETE statements that use a subquery to modify a single table is that the optimizer does not use semi-join or materialization subquery optimizations. As a workaround, try rewriting them as multiple-table UPDATE and DELETE statements that use a join rather than a subquery.